# Add pointers or cursors to non-input gameobjects

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I have a unity scene where I have a gameobject and I would like a pokepointer (or far rays) to follow that gameobject's transform, trying to make it interact with MRTK's UI prefabs at runtime. How should I set this up?
I have tried dropping the PokePointer prefab onto the gameobject, but the pointer gets destroyed immediately. Not sure if this has to do with having multiple pointers at the same time.
Is there extra setup in profiles I might be missing?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your business requirements? Making the pointer to follow that GameObject's transform is a very rare requirement.  And the far pointer provided by Hololens1 for interaction is GGVPointer, which is driven by the position and rotation of the head, and it will exactly match the position and rotation of the head.  So, making the pointer follow GameObject will conflict with the interaction model.

Comment: If you want to interact with MRTK UI prefabs without gazing at it, custom events may be more suitable for your scenario: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html#create-custom-events

Comment: For example you could have the new "Coach Hands" interact with objects, or make virtual characters interact in the same way as a user would.

Answer (score 0):

We believe that not a good practice to make rays follow GameObjects' transform. There is definitely some possibilities for cognitive dissonance and will not help to improve user's interaction confidence.  We felt that showing users how to perform an action by demonstrating the correct hand and finger placement and without interacting with other objects would be the best option. You can learn more about the recommended design for hand coach from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/hand-coach

If you insist on doing the approach you are taking, you may need to re-implement interaction with collision triggers and events, which will not be an easy route.